# CSS and Javascript loads too long on Tomcat 8 or 9

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, tomcat

I have JSF application and it works fine when I run it on embedded Jetty server. However, when I deploy it to Tomcat 8.0.35 loading of the CSS and Javascript files takes more than 20 seconds. I have the same problem on the Tomcat running on Amazon AWS server and on the Tomcat running on local machine. These are all small files and none of them is loaded longer than 35ms on Jetty server.

Tomcat logs do not indicate any kind of problems with the application, and this is happening on every page, even on the login page.

The same problem I have with Tomcat 8 and Tomcat 9, but not with Tomcat 7.

I would appreciate if somebody could give me idea what should I check or how to search for the source of the problem.

**Edit:**
 This is a h:head section of login page, but same problem is everywhere else:

```
<h:head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/zvv0dgl.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
<title>ProSolo - Sign in</title>
<link href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css2/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css2/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css2/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Edit 2 (web.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     metadata-complete="true" version="3.0">
    <display-name>ProSolo</display-name>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.prosolo.services.upload.FileServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>basePath</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/files/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
    <filter-name>opensessioninview</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.prosolo.core.spring.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>opensessioninview</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
    <filter-name>Login Partial Response Redirect</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.prosolo.core.jsf.LoginPartialResponseRedirectFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Login Partial Response Redirect</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!--  
    <filter>
      <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.prosolo.core.jsf.primefaces.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    -->
    <filter>
    <filter-name>gzipResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>gzipResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.prosolo.core.spring.SpringConfig,
        org.prosolo.core.spring.security.SpringSecurityConfig,
        org.prosolo.core.hibernate.HibernateConfig
    </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- added for p:fileUpload, options: auto, native, commons-->
    <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>native</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.prosolo.app.BeforeContextLoader</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.prosolo.app.AfterContextLoader</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.prosolo.web.SessionCountListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/login.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/login.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <!-- In Production change javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD to -1 and javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE to 'Production' -->
    <!-- In Development change javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD to 1 and javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE to 'Development' -->
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/functions.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
    <param-value>***************************</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
    <param-value>********************************</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>
    <param-value>20</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.COMPRESS_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.annotation.SCAN_PACKAGES</param-name>
    <param-value>org.prosolo.web</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_JSF_2_ALLOW_SLASH_LIBRARY_NAME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.USE_ENCRYPTION</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALGORITHM</param-name>
    <param-value>AES</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SECRET</param-name>
    <param-value>Q0hBTkdFIFNFQ1JFVCEhIQ==</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.MAC_SECRET</param-name>
    <param-value>Q0hBTkdFIE1BQ1NFQ1JFVA==</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.RESOURCE_EXCLUDES</param-name>
    <param-value>.class .jsp .jspx .properties .xhtml .xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
    <param-value>165535</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.RewriteServletRequestListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.RewriteServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
    <filter-name>OCPsoft Rewrite Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OCPsoft Rewrite Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- <filter>
     <filter-name>Save Page Url In Session Filter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.prosolo.core.jsf.SavePageUrlInSessionFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>Save Page Url In Session Filter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
     <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
   </filter-mapping> -->
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommand direct link to CSS files and java script using `<script>` and `<link>`  , and to overcome the issue of relative path , prefix the url with `#{request.contextPath}`, for example , to reference `resources/css/app.css` , use:
`<link href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

For more information , check my article  "[Java Server Faces in Real-Life Applications](https://dzone.com/articles/java-server-faces-in-real-life-applications)" at dzone .

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jalal. It is, however, connected exactly in that way you suggested, e.g. <link href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css2/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Actually, all those resources referenced in that way are loaded for 20 seconds on Tomcat 8 and 9, and jquery.min.js which is loaded from the web is loaded instantly.

Comment: can you paste your <h:head> section?

Comment: Please check my edit. You can also see my demo server which runs at the moment application on two Tomcat instances. Tomcat 7 link is http://demo.prosolo.ca:8080/prosolo, and Tomcat 8 link is http://demo.prosolo.ca:8081/prosolo.

Comment: One thing that I noticed is that in the Chrome, the second time some css or js is used, it is pulled from cache, so it runs fast. It is not the case with the Firefox. It always runs slowly.

Comment: I am unable to access the tomcat 8 link, either because of firewall config or because tomcat 8 server is down.
Note: I have already disabled the timeout on firefix.
Not related note :  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> should appear o the first line in head tag to take effect on IE , it can be done by enclosing it in <f:facet name="first"> tag.

Comment: Sorry. It was opened only for my IP address. Now it should be available.

Comment: I have just tested the client side code on my local tomcat 8 on my machine(created web project,created new test.xhtml page , downlaoded the script and css resources into project a) and it opens instantly. I believe your issue is server side (filters or config) and not related to the client-side resource.

Can you you put your web.xml ?

Comment: I added web.xml in the original question. The only difference is that FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD and PROJECT_STAGE are in development mode on the server demo.

Comment: There is a lot of stuff in your web.xml can cause issues, and such mixing of frameworks and api's can cause a mess (myfaces, primefaces, spring)my advise is as following , for now: (1) remove every thing from your web.xml the (filters and listeners)and test(most probably it will works), if solved , then start adding filters one by one until problem solved.if not please let me know. (2) for future bottlenecks : add extensive logging to your filters and listeners to include timestamps with milliseconds, to be able to track the logs for such delays.

Comment: Also, please remove the captcha keys and security keys (such as myfaces) from the question above for security purposes.

Comment: Great idea. After adding filters I came to the GzipResponseFilter as the one that causes problem, and that problem was already reported here https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/65, so I only had to change version of omnifaces to the one that has a bug fix. Thanks for your help.